# Can I install Parallels alongside Boot Camp?

Tags: bootcamp

I have a 24" iMac and have used Boot Camp to install Vista on a 100GB partition of the hard drive. Can I install Parallels Desktop as well so it will be easier to switch between Mac and Windows?

I have 4GB of RAM. Is that enough to run Parallels?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install Parallels on your Mac in addition to Boot Camp. Keep in mind that this takes a fair amount of hard drive space, so be sure you've got the space to spare.

As for your memory situation: I run Parallels on a MacBook with 4GB or RAM. It works okay, but it's rather slow. Most things will run acceptably, but performance will be better using Boot Camp.

I should also point out that this setup will be a bit of a hassle. Since the two Windows systems will be independent of each other, any changes you make on one *will not* copy over to the other system. That means that it could take a fair bit of work to keep both systems synchronized and up to date.

Comment: It's possible to boot and run a Boot Camp partition in Parallels, and then any changes you make while running it in Parallels will carry over to a direct Boot Camp boot, and vice versa. http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v6/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/23112.htm

Comment: Thanks guys. So Mike, I only have to follow the "Creating a Boot Camp Virtual Machine" on that page? Not the Import part, or?

Comment: @Claes Yes, that's correct, follow the first part of the instructions. The second part will create a VM that's a copy of your Boot Camp partition, but it will be a separate instance.

Comment: Im not sure how it works, but would it be better to uninstall windows with the bootcamp and only install parallels instead? What would be the differens?

Comment: @MikeScott Definitely worth a separate answer to vote for.